# Error in opening an mail attached excel file created using Apache POI

Tags: java, gwt, apache-poi

I am creating an excel sheet using Apache POI and then sending the same file using Java GWT.The file created is all right.Now in the mail there are two options- Save or open.When I save the file in machine it is working fine but when I try to open ,it opens in notepad.In the suggestion too it is not showing excel. Here is my code to create the excel sheet:

```
package com.ericsson.egi.sxs.utils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import com.ericsson.egi.sxs.persistence.entity.AssetOrder;

public class CreateExcelFile {

    int rownum = 0;
    HSSFSheet firstSheet;
    Collection<File> files;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook;

     CreateExcelFile() {
    }

    public File createWeeklyReport(List<AssetOrder> tempOrderList) throws Exception {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            firstSheet = workbook.createSheet("FIRST SHEET");
            List<String> headerRow = new ArrayList<String>();
            headerRow.add("Name of Supplier/Vendor");
            headerRow.add("Description of Contract");
            headerRow.add("Initiator");
            headerRow.add("Type Of Contract");
            headerRow.add("Template Source");
            headerRow.add("Savings");
            headerRow.add("Payment Term");
            headerRow.add("Code of Conduct Signed by Supplier");
            headerRow.add("RoHS clause Included");
            headerRow.add("Agreement No");
            headerRow.add("Agreement Validity From ");
            headerRow.add("Agreement Validity To");
            headerRow.add("Sanctioned Parties List Screening");
            headerRow.add("Sanctioned Parties List Screening Reasons in case no answer NO");
            headerRow.add("Registered in CLM");
            headerRow.add("Registered in CLM reasons if answer NO");
            headerRow.add("Current State");
            headerRow.add("Next State");
            headerRow.add("TAT for L1");
            headerRow.add("TAT for L2");
            headerRow.add("TAT for L3");
            headerRow.add("TAT for L4");
            headerRow.add("Current State Comments");

            List<List> recordToAdd = new ArrayList<List>();
            recordToAdd.add(headerRow); 
            for (AssetOrder order : tempOrderList ) {
                List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getVendorName());
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getContractDescription());
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getInitiatorName());
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getContractType());
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getTemplateSource()); 
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getSavings());
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getPaymentTerm()); 
                if (order.getSourcingDetails().getIsCOCSigned()) {
                    row.add("YES");
                } else {
                    row.add("NO");
                }

                if (order.getSourcingDetails().getIsROHSIncluded()) {
                    row.add("YES");
                } else {
                    row.add("NO"); 
                }
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getAgreementNo());
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getValidityFrom().toString()); 
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getValidityTo().toString());
                if (order.getSourcingDetails().getIsSPLScreening()) {
                    row.add("YES");
                } else {
                    row.add("NO");
                }
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getReasonsForSPL());
                if (order.getSourcingDetails().getIsRegisteredInCLM()) {
                    row.add("YES");
                } else {
                    row.add("NO");
                }
                row.add(order.getSourcingDetails().getReasonsForCLM());
                row.add(order.getStatusMaster().getStatusName()); 
                row.add(null);
                row.add(null); 
                row.add(null);
                row.add(null); 
                row.add(null);
                row.add(order.getComments()); 

                recordToAdd.add(row);
            }

            CreateExcelFile cls = new CreateExcelFile(recordToAdd);
            File file = cls.createExcelFile(tempOrderList.get(0).getOrderRequesterSignum());           
            return file;
        }

        File createExcelFile(String requesterSignum) {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            File file = new File("/tmp/" + requesterSignum + "_StatusReport.xls");
            try {

                fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
                HSSFCellStyle hsfstyle=workbook.createCellStyle();
                hsfstyle.setBorderBottom((short) 1);
                hsfstyle.setFillBackgroundColor((short)245);

                workbook.write(fos);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return file;
        }

         CreateExcelFile(List<List> l1) throws Exception {
         try {
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                firstSheet = workbook.createSheet("FIRST SHEET");
                for (int j = 0; j < l1.size(); j++) {
                    Row row = firstSheet.createRow(rownum);
                    List<String> l2= l1.get(j);

                    for(int k=0; k<l2.size(); k++)
                    {
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(k);
                        cell.setCellValue(l2.get(k));
                    }
                    rownum++;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: Do you have Excel installed on your machine? What happens if you try to start Excel first and then navigate to the file?

Comment: Yes Excel is installed in my machine.When I download the attached file its working fine.When I try to directly open it then its not taking excel as an option.

Comment: Are you working on Windows?

Comment: No.Linux.But the problem is same in both the OS.

Comment: Is the problem related to setContentType or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try with other [Excel Extension](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-HP010014103.aspx) as per your Excel version installed on your machine.

---

--EDIT--

May be the issue is related to Content Type. Please confirm what are you using for this?

```
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");

// try this one if above doesn't work
//response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myExcel.xls");
```

Comment: What have you set as content type?

Comment: I have used the content type to setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); .When I forward the same mail to my gmail then its working completely fine.So is the problem lying in outlook?

Comment: I think its a thunderbird mail issue.Because same is working in gmail,yahoo mail or any other mail

Comment: @Atul Sorry I don't have any idea about mail API. Have your tried with `APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM`?

Comment: yes sir.it did not work.Actually I tried a different excel file which had no relation with code to open from attachment in thunderbird mail.but the problem remains same.So I concluded that there is nothing wrong with the code. Thanks for the help :) Have a great day.